# Do I Ressemble a Cheetos?

Tags: riddle, word

> Can your criticisms please stop?
>
> All you say are crap
>
> Robert, stop teasing me for my height
>
> Raphaelle, i don’t care if I ressemble a Cheetos
>
> Oh my dear lord, I’m
>
> Tearing myself apart

*What am I?*

Comment: rot13(Gur npebfgvp fnlf pneebg) but I'm not sure what that hints toward (maybe that is the answer)

Comment: If it's the answer then the riddle is almost all "chaff". I'm sure we're not the only people who've noticed rot13(gur npebfgvp) but not posted an answer because surely there must be more going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like this can't be the answer, but I'll give it a go anyway!

> This puzzle seems to be an acrostic puzzle, as the acrostic gives us CARROT. Also, adding to the "confusion", carrots do in a way resemble Cheetos. More specifically, the carrot could be baby carrot as one of the lines says "stop teasing me for my height". Lastly, thanks to Belhenix, a baby carrot tends to split through the middle thus explaining the last line.

So the answer I am going with is:

> It is a baby carrot

Comment: I saw that acrostic too but what do you think the lines are referring to? I didn't really have any idea

Comment: @Ahmed I added a bit to make it a tad more specific

Comment: Also, rot13(Pneebgf graq gb fcyvg guebhtu gur zvqqyr, znxvat n pbafvqrenoyr tnc va abezny pneebgf ohg n uhtr bar va gurve onol inevnagf, fbzrgvzrf fcnaavat gur jubyr irtrgnoyr.) could explain the last 2 lines

Comment: @Belhenix Perfect, I didn't even think of that! I'll add that to my answer!

Comment: It’s correct, good job!!